# Python TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, oop, module

My main script
"main.py"

```
from Hero import Knight

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print('hello')

  Arture = Knight('Arture')
  print(Arture.hp)
```

class "Hero" in derictory Hero
"Hero.py"

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Hero(ABC):

def __init__(self, name):
    self.__name = name

@abstractmethod
def set_hp(self):
    pass

def get_hp(self):
    return self.hp

hp = property(get_hp, set_hp)
```

class "Knight" in derictory Hero
"Knight.py"

```
import Hero
class Knight(Hero):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def set_hp(self):
        self.__hp = 100

    def min_hp(self, value):
        self.__hp -= value
```

I have file _*init* but he are based

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\game\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Hero import Knight
  File "D:\python\game\Hero\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Hero import Knight
  File "D:\python\game\Hero\Knight.py", line 2, in <module>
    class Knight(Hero):
TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Why I get this error if I set only one argument in constructor Knight?

Comment: in Hero.py try `class Hero(abc.ABC):` not sure but might be a class definition or inheritance issue

Comment: `Hero` is a _module_.  Presumably you intended to make the Knight class inherit from the Hero _class_ (which is inside the Hero module), not the Hero module itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fix your indentation of the constructor in `class Hero(ABC):`

```
class Hero(ABC):

def __init__(self, name):
    self.__name = name
```

Then, as mentioned in the comments above, you want to import the *class* not the *module*.  So change your import statement of `Knight.py` to be `from Hero.Hero import Hero`.

And also in `main.py` you need to make the import be `from Hero.Knight import Knight`.  (This is assuming you have `Knight` and `Hero` in a folder called `Hero` as you mentioned.)

Now you have a problem of calling the constructor properly.  You'll get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    Arture = Knight('Arture')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Knight.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This is because it doesn't see the superclass.  You need to call it.  So together, for `Knight.py` you'll have:

```
from Hero.Hero import Hero
class Knight(Hero):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

    def set_hp(self):
        self.__hp = 100

    def min_hp(self, value):
        self.__hp -= value
```

With those changes, you'll hit the problem of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(Arture.hp)
          ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Knight' object has no attribute 'hp'
```

but that is because you didn't include `hp` in your class. I'm not sure what you were trying to do with that based on the indentation.